# Deleting multiple user in google app education

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

How do I remove bulk users from our education account, say students who have graduated so that their emails will not be used for something else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete users from an Education account or domain similar to a regular Google Workspace domain, please check the instructions on this page:

[Delete or remove a user from your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314?hl=en)

If you want to delete users programatically, you can make use of Admin SDK API's on this page:

[Admin SDK - Manage Users / Delete User](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#delete_user)

[REST API Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/delete)

Comment: Thank you @Carlos M, I have gone through that but unfortunately it will display 50 users per row, I was thinking that there is/are apps/scripts that one can run that will remove lots of user using something like a wildcard ???.???2010@email.edu.ng

Comment: @osagiesammy I might guess that the users are in a collection and perhaps you need to use pagetokens to get all of your results.  Just a guess.

Comment: You would need to make use of API's from this reference page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#delete_user